# Laravel Echo Server , Socket IO , Nginx problem

Tags: node.js, laravel, nginx, websocket, laravel-echo

we are trying to use laravel echo server , socket io , redis on nginx webserver for a page that we need to have real time informations on it , our laravel website and realtime is working on local server but when we deploy on server we get error and it doesnt work ;

we get the following error on console ;
`app.js:5562 WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain.com:6001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:`

and WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain.com:6001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:

for this we are using the following ;

nginx website config :

```
 location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass https://domainname.com:6001; #could be localhost if Echo and NginX are on the same box
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
```

and also ;

laravel-echo-server.js ;

```
    "authHost": "http://localhost",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

bootstrap.js

```
  GNU nano 6.2                                           bootstrap.js                                                    
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ":" + window.laravel_echo_port,
    transports: ["websocket", 'polling'],
});
```

we also started laravel-echo-server on server

Comment: It might not answer your question, but I would recommend use soketi instead laravel-echo-server. Alternatively you could use a free Pusher cloud setup. (200,000 events per day in free plan).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to connect to the socket throgh secure connection(wss)
Is your socket server using certification for handling secure connections?

https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-initialization/#with-an-https-server